# Disable keyboard from code

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I am trying to disable to keyboard of my iOS device. I know that it can be done via Hardware -> Keyboard -> Connect Hardware Keyboard. But I want to do it in code. Does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: Why do u want to disable keyboard? Whats the use-case?

Comment: I am writing UITests. There is a bug with fields that contain passwords. This bug can be solved by disabling they keyboard.

Comment: You can disable the `textfield` itself.

Comment: This wont solve the problem - since i need to enter something in the textfield.(The bug is actually that in the UITest the field will be taped - however it does not recognize that it is tapped) I found a workaround that copies the text and posts it into the field.

Comment: Add this code below your question..

Comment: Then, how will u enter text with keyboard disabled? Are u using external keyboard? BTW, even after disabling the keyboard, you can paste in the textfield (programmatically ofcourse)

Comment: The framework for UITesting does all the actions - all i do is call the methods in the test classes. It works fine for regular textFields - only when i try to add it to a field that contains a password, it fails.

Answer (score 1):

For everyone that has the same problem. I found a workaround that copies and pasts the text.

```
    UIPasteboard.generalPasteboard().string = pw
    textField.pressForDuration(1.1)
    app.menuItems["Paste"].tap()
```